# Subversion: how to check out a Windows repository on a Mac?

Tags: svn

I have a repository on a Windows 7 machine that I would like to checkout on my MacBook.  These two machines are on the same network.  Using TortoiseSVN on other Windows machines there is no problem, however, when I try and check out the repository on my Mac, I get "Unable to open repository".  My repo URL is of the form "file://hostname/repo".  Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Andrew

Comment: How about `svn+ssh://hostname/repo`?

Comment: It shouldn't matter what operating system you are using to access svn. What svn client are you using mac-side?

Comment: @Hans, subversive command line.

Comment: @Jack, I've tried this already with no luck -- the connection times out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While file-based Subversion repository access works fine for 1 user, 1 machine, you may want to consider running a Subversion server once multiple computers (or users) are involved. I suspect in your case it's an issue with Windows file sharing to your MacBook, but suggest running a Subversion server to fix your issue.

See: [Choosing a Server Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html) from the [Subversion 1.7 Manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html)

If you decide not to do so, try accessing the folder without involving a Subversion client from your Mac and ensure that works - I suspect the reason it won't checkout is because it can't access the fileshare.

Comment: "because it can't access the fileshare" -- is this because of the Mac/Windows incompatibility? Or do I need to enable this.  For my other Windows machines, I simply enabled users to access the fileshare, not specific machines.

Comment: In any case, I'll try setting up a server.  Thanks for the pointer to the manual.

Comment: It's not an incompatibility necessarily, Macs can definitely access windows file shares, but you may need to explicitly enter some authentication info (something your Subversion client may not be prompting you for correctly when you try to access that file:// URL) that Windows may be figuring out on its own if the PCs are on a workgroup or homegroup. It's just a wild guess, though :)